# GDI SetWindowRgn is extremely slow for complex window shapes

Tags: windows, user-interface, mfc, window, gdi

Our application creates an overlay window of a custom shape using the `SetWindowRgn()` API in its `OnPaint()` function. This region window only has a client area. It also has an owner window which is a regular rectangular window.

We have observed that sometimes the `SetWindowRgn()` call in `OnPaint()` takes a long time to return if the shape of the region is complex, for example, if the window region is a text or a complex design. Even the window below this region window renders slowly. This mostly occurs on resizing the view. What we have found is that `OnNcCalcSize()` gets called from inside `SetWindowRgn()` and the default handling of `OnNcCalcSize()` takes a long time to return. Also, on some machines, the painting of the window below the region window is very slow.

Why does the rendering of a region window become slow for complex shapes? Can we make it faster by custom handling of events like `OnNcCalcSize()` or other events?

**NOTE:** Please don't suggest using a Layered window as a technical limitation has forced us to use a region window.

Comment: Regions are things from the past with known mysterious issues when mixed with recent OSes and things from the present (WPF, DirectX, Direct2D, DWM, layered, transparency, etc.). Difficult to say w/o anything to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Hard to guess what the problem is. You should post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I don't know if I could spot the problem myself.

Comment: Do you HAVE to call SetWindowRgn() from OnPaint()? This sounds wrong...